# Generic layout button

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm making a layout for a menu, and all my buttons have all the same height, the same width, the same background color, ...
Is it possible to create a basic button, with all these informations and without the text and the onclick attribute, and then place it N times in the xml, where N is the number of items of my menu, and adding a text and an onclick attribute?

Comment: Are you writing the layout in xml, or dynamically?

Comment: I am writing it in xml directly

Comment: Then you can make a generic layout as a custom layout, and set it to have attributes of 'text' and 'onClick', but you will still have to write it into xml each time you use it. It will probably be more effort that way. If you make the menu dynamically you could do it all in a loop.

Comment: I will make it in a loop then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called styles.

You can define any style that sets any number of layout properties, then tell the view to use the style.

The styles.xml content looks like this (parent is optional)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="CodeFont" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And inside the layout you simply add it on the properties of the view like this:

```
   <TextView
    style="@style/CodeFont"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
```

Snipsets taken from the official documentation, which you can read for more details: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html